# Which PHP DOM object has the getNodePath method?

Tags: php, dom

I have seen examples of usage of a getNodePath() method on PHP DOM objects.

see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#91072

However i cannot find the documentation for that method.

I have been going around in circles in the DOM Docs.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every method and function is documented in the PHP Manual yet. If you want to find out a class' methods, you can use [Reflection](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). Either do

```
ReflectionClass::export('DOMNode');
```

or from the command line:

```
$ php --rc DOMNode
```

should give something like:

```
Class [ <internal:dom> class DOMNode ] {

   // ... lots of other stuff ...

    Method [ <internal:dom> public method getNodePath ] {

      - Parameters [0] {
      }
    }

   // ... lots of other stuff ...
}
```

If you do that for `DOMDocument`, it will tell you where it was inherited from:

```
 Method [ <internal:dom, inherits DOMNode> public method getNodePath ] {

   - Parameters [0] {
   }
 }
```

I didnt know that function btw. Handy! Thanks for asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `getNodeXPath()` like this:

```
<?php
/**
* result sample : /html[1]/body[1]/span[1]/fieldset[1]/div[1]
* @return string
*/
function getNodeXPath( $node ) {    
    $result='';
    while ($parentNode = $node->parentNode) {
        $nodeIndex=-1;
        $nodeTagIndex=0;
        do {
            $nodeIndex++;
            $testNode = $parentNode->childNodes->item( $nodeIndex );

            if ($testNode->nodeName==$node->nodeName and $testNode->parentNode->isSameNode($node->parentNode) and $testNode->childNodes->length>0) {
                //echo "{$testNode->parentNode->nodeName}-{$testNode->nodeName}-{}<br/>";
                $nodeTagIndex++;
            }

        } while (!$node->isSameNode($testNode));

        $result="/{$node->nodeName}[{$nodeTagIndex}]".$result;
        $node=$parentNode;
    };
    return $result;
}
?>
```

This is defined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#87471).

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to indicates which objects have this method:

```
        case ($obj instanceof DOMDocument):
            ... $obj->getNodePath() ...
            ...
        case ($obj instanceof DOMElement):
            ... $obj->getNodePath() ...
            ...
```

So, `DOMDocument` and `DOMElement` instances have the `getNodePath()` method. However, I wasn´t able to find any documentation in the official PHP docs, but I found a blog post apparently by the implementor of that method: http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2006/07/16/added-domnode-getnodepath.html

Comment: Thanks for that link. The author implies that it is on the DOMNode class. Which fits cos it is the parent of both  DOMDocument and DOMElement. 

However, the docs don't mention getNodePath()  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

So problem is kind of solved.

(I should have said 'class' in my question - cos that was what i was trying to work out.).